# I cant get to authenticate using Soundcloud account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, omniauth, soundcloud

Im programming an app that has to be able to allow the users to sign up using their soundcloud accounts, so far I haven't found any usefull tutorial using Omniauth, Can anyone help me giving some tips to start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave a presentation to my local meetup about integrating OmniAuth into your application using a demo application [here](https://github.com/xfernandox/babl). You can fork it and go through the steps in section 3 of the README. There are also some slides you can look at [here](https://speakerdeck.com/xfernandox/authenticate-with-omniauth).

There's a lot of refactoring that needs to still be done, but it was designed to be a basic intro start to a bunch of people who had never used OmniAuth before.

I also list resources that helped with putting together the presentation. I highly recommend checking them out.

Although the examples are not with the omniauth-soundcloud, it should work similarly.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I am still a rookie programmer and dont know how to implement that with soundcloud which seems to be a lot different than the usual facebook authentication (which I've already done), plus the official soundcloud documentation is very poor for what I need to do, I would appreciate a little more info about Soundcloud specically..

Comment: So it should be exactly the same as doing Facebook or any other OmniAuth provider who has a gem. The only change would be to the `omniauth.rb` file

https://github.com/soundcloud/omniauth-soundcloud

Add this gem to your gemfile, `bundle install` and put the code block under Basic Usage (starting w/use OmniAuth::Builder) into `config/omniauth.rb`

OmniAuth is meant to abstract the connection to Soundcloud and return a similar authentication hash no matter who the provider, so most tutorials on implementing OmniAuth should work, the only change you need to make is specifying Soundcloud.